# Should I have link rel=next & prev on URLs which have query variables?

Tags: url, search-engine-indexing, url-parameters

For example, I have link `rel prev & next` set up on these pages of products:

```
site.com?page=2
site.com?page=3
```

(this is my preferred structure by the way and I'm trying to get all the ugly URLs which are littered with query variables deindexed as they are causing duplicate content).

So the above URLs are fine but once a filter to narrow product results is selected, like "price", the URL shows like this:

```
site.com?price[1000-1499]=on
site.com?page=2&price[1000-1499]=on
```

As of right now, I am having the link `rel prev & next` dynamically added to the header of these pages but since I am working on getting these query variable URLs pages deindexed, I am wondering if I should get rid of it on these pages? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The `rel` values `next` and `prev` are not only useful to search engines. They denote the relationship type, i.e. how the link target is related to the current page.

So, why would you want to omit them? They have no influence on (de)indexing if you block the pages with `robots.txt` resp. `robots`-`meta`.

You wouldn’t stop using semantic HTML for pages to be deindexed either, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working to get these deindexed then there is no point having these tags as Google wont read them.

I would probably  also block these types of pages myself, as more than likely they will just be duplicate pages if they are 'sort-by' options.